# Best Practice to handle items modification in SharePoint 2007

Tags: list, best-practices, check-out

From my understanding, there is no checkout function inside a SharePoint 2007 List.

So, what is the best practice that SharePoint Professionals and Expert do to make sure that a item of a SharePoint 2007 List is not modify concurrently? (meaning that there are two person who is perform modification to the item and only the last modification is apply to the item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't checkout on SharePoint lists (there is on document libraries) - SharePoint uses optimistic concurrency rather than pessimistic concurrency - e.g.

- User A opens up edit form and starts editing
- User B opens up ...
- User A saves
- User B clicks save but SP warns them that the data has
  changed since they started editing and will make the user B view User A's changes and re-enter.

For most use cases this is sufficient as an edit on a list item will generally be started and completed pretty quickly (as opposed to a document that could be being edited for hours or days) so the chance of this occurring is small.

Can I ask what use case and load that you're expecting this to be a problem for? Is this actually causing a problem now or are you perhaps over engineering? (no offence intended)

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the reply. May I know if "SP warns user B that the data has changed since they started editing" also apply for SPServices?

Comment: Don't know about SPServices. The web service and object model all throw errors in this situation but it would be up to the client program to display this to the user.

Comment: Hi Ryan, just to answer your question - the load may be like 30 request per minute in the 1st hour and last hour of a working day. I am just preparing in advance in case it peak over 60 request to 100 request per minute.

Comment: Are these 30 requests per minute actually updates to the SAME list item?

Comment: Yes, 30 requests per minute to update the SAME list item.

Comment: You're definitely going to hit problems then and have a very frustrating app to use as people are continually forced to re-enter. Open up a new question with details of what your doing, how users are updating the list item etc and see what the community can come up with re: alternative designs (perhaps users have own record and its then summarised) or schemes that will work with this level of usage. Difficult to say without details of what you're looking to do.