# Send SP warning message on another user changes in a SharePoint item to SPServices

Tags: 2007, spservices

From my understanding from this post (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23597/best-practice-to-handle-items-modification-in-sharepoint-2007), SharePoint uses optimistic concurreny e.g.

- User A opens up edit form and starts editing
- User B opens up ...
- User A saves
- User B clicks save but SP warns them that the data has changed since
  they started editing and will make the user B view User A's changes and re-enter.

Currently, I have a HTML form that will allow user to edit some list items, so I was wondering what I should do in SPServices to do the following:

- getting that SP warning message for User B and
- getting that User A's changes into the HTML form so that User B can
  view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you update an item, one of the fields returned is the latest changed date/time. You can build your concurrency logic using that date/time, looking at it vs. the date/time prior to your update. It will require a few extra Web Service calls, but if it's important to maintain integrity, it works.

Comment: I think that multi workflows (which you describe as concurrency logic) will be pretty useful.